# Is there a better way to create a flower by geometric node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am following this tutoial to make a follower by geometric node. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqRVxosrnGc&t=19s

I can follow the tutorial until he made a leaf around 11 minutes shown in the picture. I am not sure why I cannot get the same result. Is there a better way to make a flower like this by geometric node? It seems there are some steps(make points and change orientation by Euler) overlapping with each other in the tutorial.

My file: https://blend-exchange.com/b/6OVsLdPn

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Most of the tutorials work, if you follow EXACTLY the one who makes it. Don't change anything, don't even scale in object mode if the tutorials scales in edit mode - this can mess it all up! (i am speaking of own bad experiences...)
2. you "missed" the important point here: at 11:06 he says: make sure you pose it like that, and as you can see he has a rotation of 90 in x and 0 in y and z. His leaf is pointing upward in z direction.

[image]

This is your leaf:

[image]

so change x to 90 and y to 0.

Enter edit mode, A to select all, and move (with G) and rotate (with R) the leaf that it looks like his model with the right direction and rotation and (!) the right origin point. Then it works.

and you have to set the factor here to 1: (not 0)

[image]